# Hyperbolic vs Euclidean Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, brownian-motion, hyperbolic-geometry

In [***this***](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Papers/hyperbolicBBM.pdf) article, page 4 of the linked pdf file, Lalley and Sellke claim that a hyperbolic Brownian motion can be obtained by time-changing a 2-dimensional Euclidean Brownian motion, conditioned to stop at the $x$-axis. In their construction, it is not clear how the time-change is implemented.

Can anyone suggest references that explore this idea of time-change in detail? Particularly for the Poincaré disk model.

Comment: This _feels_ like it's related to the notion of Wick rotation in physics, which maps a Minkowski metric to a Euclidean metric via analytic continuation (which is more or less like going from a hyperbolic geometry to a Euclidean one). But I don't know how to formulate that in a precise or helpful way...

Comment: The time change $t \mapsto \rho(t)$ is the implicit formula given on the bottom of page 4 (the last displayed formula reading $t = \int_0^{\rho(t)} \ldots$. The point is very simple: the generator of the diffusion on two-dimension Euclidean space is $\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$, while the generator of the diffusion on two-dimensional Hyperbolic space in the half plane model takes the form $y^2(\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2)$. So if you can some how absorb the $y^2$ factor by reparametrising time (which is the formula I referred to), you can convert the hyperbolic Brownian motion to Euclidean.

Comment: For the disc model the generator is (up to constant factors) $(1 - x^2 - y^2)(\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2)$, so you should be able to simply replace the $Y^{-2}$ factor in the formula for $t$ by $(1 - X^2 - Y^2)^{-1}$. (I suppressed the subscripts for brevity.)

Comment: It's so unclear what you're asking. I don't have the attention span to study your link carefully. Maybe somebody focuses on one question at a time and takes longer to give up on it. If you want a better chance of getting an answer that solves your problem, you're more likely to get one if you explain make it clear what you're looking for.